# Android + Facebook SDK : "Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch."

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

While trying to use Facebook SDK on my Android App, I got this error:

"Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch. Please check the application name configured by the dialog."

After reading many posts on this subject, from other people getting the same issue and succeeded in correcting it, it's still impossible for me to get the Facebook SDK working… I suppose there is something wrong between the app configuration on Facebook and my Android project, but I don't understand what.

This is my application configuration on Facebook :

- App ID : 752068304844308
- Display name : TestFSdk
- namespace : lbptestfsdk

The configuration for Android on Facebook :

- Package name : fr.laposte.testfsdk
- Class name : fr.laposte.testfsdk.MainActivity
- Key hash : the one i get with key tool + openssl (android debug key)
- Single Sign On : yes
- Deep Linking : no

And my Android project :

- Eclipse project name : TestFSdk (is it important ?)
- Activity class using FB SDK : fr.laposte.testfsdk.MainActivity
- strings.xml contains :

  ```
  <string name="app_id">752068304844308</string>
  <string name="app_name">TestFSdk</string>     --> is it usefull ?
  ```
- AndroidManifest.xml :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="fr.laposte.testfsdk"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >
      <uses-sdk
          android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
          <activity
              android:name="fr.laposte.testfsdk.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity
              android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
      </application>
  </manifest>
  ```

Do you see something wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Please check name in app(in your manifest file) and name of application on facebook().

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I was using `SetApplicationName()` in the *ShareDialogBuilder* to set a name that was different to the facebook Display Name. They must match!

Comment: ShareDialogBuilder has been deprecated
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.7/class/FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder/

Answer (score 1):

According to documents
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share?locale=es_ES

and add

`.setApplicationName("Display Name")`

Comment: Although your answer is correct, this page now redirects to another page which does not contain this information.

Comment: FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder .setApplicationName("Display Name")
has been deprecated.

Comment: @johanson and what has it been replaced by since ?